# Skip underscore in numbers antlr4

Tags: regex, antlr4

I'm writing a token that can parse numbers with the underscore, the number should start with a number in [0-9].

I did:

`INT: [0-9]+([0-9]|(('_')->channel(HIDDEN)))*`

and it will not skip the underscore for me including the first place, say, `_1234` is parsed as `_1234` and `123_4` is also parsed as `123_4` which makes me feel confused. How could the first case not failing when it can only be captured by [0-9], and how could the second case failing for hiding underscores?

For example:

1. If I want to capture `1234_56`, my token should return `123456`
2. If I want to capture `_1234`, my token should return `1234`

Comment: can you give examples of strings that should and shouldn't match? Are you just trying to capture the numeric part of the input? What is the "->channel(HIDDEN))" part intended for?

Comment: @mangotang Yes, I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule

```
INT: [0-9]+ ([0-9]|(('_')->channel(HIDDEN)))* ;
```

will generate a `lexer command placement` error due to the location of the `-> channel` command. A generation error means the generated lexer/parser should not be considered valid. Operation can be subtlety to wildly unpredictable.

To be valid, the command has to exist on the right edge of a lexer rule. It cannot be simply embedded in a rule.

Best recommendation is to use the lexer to accept valid *input* text only (*i.e.*, not try to rewrite the *input* text to some other form).

```
INT: [0-9]+ ([0-9]|'_')* ;
```

When performing the eventual output operations -- actions on parser rules or a tree walker -- `INT` token values can then be converted to the desired output form.

Comment: You can simplify `([0-9]|'_')*` to `[0-9_]*`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Since I've already have [0-9] to capture the first digits, it can be simplified to `INT: [0-9][0-9_]*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with python

example:

```
INTLIT: ( OCT | HEX | BIN | DEC ) {self.text = self.text.replace('_','')}
```